# How to convert torch tensor to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I'd like to convert a torch tensor to pandas dataframe but by using `pd.DataFrame` I'm getting a dataframe filled with tensors instead of numeric values.

```py
import torch
import pandas as  pd
x = torch.rand(4,4)
px = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Here's what I get when clicking on `px` in the variable explorer:

```
0   1   2   3
tensor(0.3880)  tensor(0.4598)  tensor(0.4239)  tensor(0.7376)
tensor(0.4174)  tensor(0.9581)  tensor(0.0987)  tensor(0.6359)
tensor(0.6199)  tensor(0.8235)  tensor(0.9947)  tensor(0.9679)
tensor(0.7164)  tensor(0.9270)  tensor(0.7853)  tensor(0.6921)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found one possible way by converting torch first to numpy:

```
import torch
import pandas as  pd

x = torch.rand(4,4)
px = pd.DataFrame(x.numpy())
```

Comment: This is faster than Dishin's answer

Comment: if your tensors have gradients, you should use `tensor.detach().numpy()` to avoid errors when trying to convert the gradients to numpy

Answer (score 12):

You can change type using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```py
px = pd.DataFrame(x).astype("float")
px
          0         1         2         3
0  0.847408  0.714524  0.286006  0.165475
1  0.136359  0.384073  0.398055  0.437550
2  0.843704  0.301536  0.576983  0.231726
3  0.293576  0.075563  0.811282  0.881705
```