# How to add in cell of DataFrame all tensor?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pytorch, tensor

I have a two-dimensional tensor and I want to make a Dataframe with one column out of it so that it doesn't split into separate values.

Something like that:

```
import torch
import pandas as  pd

x = torch.rand(4,3)
x
>>> tensor([[0.8888, 0.8168, 0.2737],
            [0.9429, 0.0847, 0.6115],
            [0.3147, 0.5715, 0.9937],
            [0.5592, 0.7696, 0.3094]])

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df
>>> tensor([0.8888, 0.8168, 0.2737])
    tensor([0.9429, 0.0847, 0.6115])
    tensor([0.3147, 0.5715, 0.9937])
    tensor([0.5592, 0.7696, 0.3094])
df.shape
>>> (4, 1)
```

Help me, please, I will be very grateful.

I tried to use a cycle to add tensors by rows. I tried converting it to an array first. It is constantly evolving into separate values in each column.

Comment: Welcome. Does this answer your question? [How to convert torch tensor to pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942487/how-to-convert-torch-tensor-to-pandas-dataframe). Please also post your expected output because it isn't very clear what you mean with *Dataframe with one column (...) so that it doesn't split into separate values*. At least that link will get you a pandas dataframe. we may see to the shape next.

Comment: `df.shape >>> (4, 1)` means the dataframe is already single-column (and 4 rows). Isn't this what you said you wanted?